# fail execute statement with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, md5

I insert the users output like this:

```
  $userName= SanitizeString($userName);
  $pass= SanitizeString($pass);
  $email= SanitizeString($email);

  $userName=mysql_real_escape_string($userName);
  $pass=mysql_real_escape_string($pass);
  $email=mysql_real_escape_string($email);

  $salt = 'SHIFLETT';
  $password_hash = md5($salt . md5($pass.$salt));

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (user_name,pass,email,reputation,role,ban,date) VALUES ('$userName', '$password_hash', '$email', '$reputation',   '$role','false','$date')" ) or exit(mysql_error());
```

That is the SanitizeString($var) function:

```
   function SanitizeString($var)
   {
       $var=stripslashes($var);
       $var=htmlentities($var, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
       $var=strip_tags($var);
       return $var;
   }
```

But when I try to find the users password and name with this query. It fails:

```
       $user_name=SanitizeString($user_name);
   $pass=SanitizeString($pass);


  $user_name=mysql_real_escape_string($user_name);
  $pass=mysql_real_escape_string($pass);


   $salt = 'SHIFLETT';
   $password_hash = md5($salt . md5($pass.$salt));

   $result=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS Result FROM users WHERE user_name='$user_name' AND pass='$password_hash' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

if the count is greater than 0 than it means it found one result and the user should log in. But that doesnt happen..Why?

UPDATE more to this:

```
   if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
       {
           echo "Login successful".mysql_num_rows($result);
           return $dataArray=TRUE;
       }
       else
       {
           echo "Login unsuccessful:".mysql_num_rows($result);
       }
```

Comment: Are you sure the password is correct?

Comment: maybe because your password being sanitized? I think it's not neccessary, because your calculating hash

Comment: making a hash of a hash md5(md5('your text here')) is never a good idea since it makes the hash less reliable. Also try to use sha256 if possible.

Comment: what is the code you are checking result with?

Comment: doesnt salting the md5 helps?!? and makes the attack impossible. I took that algorithm from php security book published by Oreilly

Comment: @Dmitry Makovetskiyd Doing md5(md5(... could increase the risk of collision and doesn't make the string any real safer. You should be safe enought with an hash of pass+random salt, especially if you don't use md5 but sha1 or the sha2 family (256 for ex.)

Comment: alright, I will check into this.. why do I get login successful no matter what I put in the query. ..I get 1 each time..after "Login successful" how does it find rows that dont exist

Comment: because your query remains the same, silly.

Comment: is putting this better:  $password_hash = hash('sha256', $pass);.. why the query returns 1? why is it the same? how can i set up the right if statement? or query statement?

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd your `SanitizeString()` function is out of place here, don't see what good could it do at this point of the script; it can make it even more problematic, on the contrary. You target a database, so just escape for the database. Leave html escaping to output only. You might also want to `trim()` the password if it's coming from an input, before hashing it

Comment: so what do I include and exclude from it? should I use it on the user name and not on the password cause the hash algorithm does the work for me?

Comment: this hashing stuff doesn't matter. it has nothing to do with the site security. FORGET IT

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `GROUP BY` if you want to use `COUNT(*)`, but you can get the number of rows with `mysql_num_rows()` like this.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * AS Result FROM users WHERE user_name='$user_name' AND pass='$password_hash' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: Sorry me.. I know the answer of group by was irrelevant but the mysql_num_rows worked.. I need to read a bit about sha and md5

Comment: what I did is if stament..then I put $row['Result']>0 ..instead..see update

Comment: sorry the code isnt solved..I get 1 even when I put the wrong name :(