# mysql and security

Tags: php, mysql, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [fail execute statement with php and mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819273/fail-execute-statement-with-php-and-mysql)

I have this statement taking output out of the database:

```
   function ValidateLogin($user_name, $pass)
   {  

   $user_name=SanitizeString($user_name);
   $pass=SanitizeString($pass);


  $user_name=mysql_real_escape_string($user_name);
  $pass=mysql_real_escape_string($pass);


   $salt = 'SHIFLETT';
   $password_hash = hash('sha256',$salt.hash('sha256', $pass));

   $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$user_name' AND pass='$password_hash' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());


   $dataArray=FALSE;


       if(mysql_num_rows($result))
       {
           echo "Login successful".mysql_num_rows($result);
           return $dataArray=TRUE;
       }
       else
       {
           echo "Login unsuccessful:".mysql_num_rows($result);
       }
       return $dataArray;

       mysql_close();
  }
```

The sanitize function is:

```
function SanitizeString($var)
{
       $var=stripslashes($var);
       $var=htmlentities($var, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
       $var=strip_tags($var);
       $var=trim($var);
       return $var;
}
```

Note on the insert I use the same hash algorithm. ... what I get here is always zero:
`echo "Login unsuccessful:".mysql_num_rows($result);`

Is mysql statement wrong..or is it the hash algorithm? or the sanitizeString function?

UPDATE:

result:
before the $pass is hashed I get this:

```
string(5) "Mad24"
string(1) "1"
```

when I insert the name and pass to the database. I get this:

```
string(5) "Mad24"
string(8) "luckyd55"
```

Again this is before the pass is hashed on the insert and login of the user.  why when I login I get `1`?!?!?
\

The login form

```
   echo '
      <form action="" method="POST">
      <table width="80%" border="1" cellpadding="10" id="navigationBar">
          <tr>
            <td> <a href="StoredProcedure/User/Registration.php">Register</a></td>
            <td> <a href="/PoliticalForum/controlPanel.php">Control Panel</a></td>
            <td> <a href="/PoliticalForum/checkEmail.php">Donate</a> </td>
            <td align="right">name:<input name="name" type="text" /></td>
            <td>password:<input name="pass" type="password" /> <input name="login" type="submit" value="Login" /> </td>
          </tr>
       </table>
           </form>
       ';
```

Comment: Not an answer but it looks like you use the same salt for all users/passwords. You should create a random salt for each password you insert into the db.

Comment: `var_dump($user_name, $password_hash)` and check they are really same with the value in database.

Comment: On first glance I don't see any major flaw in the logic involved here. My suggestion: Try echoing the parameters `$user_name` and `$password_hash` which you are using in the SQL statement to find out if they're properly formed. You should take special care when trying to sanitize passwords, but if this is done stringent throughout your application, this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @PeeHaa Actually he doesn't use the same salt, because he's adding the sha256 of the actual password to it. A _real_ random salt would be better, but this solution ain't that bad.

Comment: hmm.. i will check now with var_dump

Comment: @Matrix001 Does your code work when you don't use your SanitizeString function? Ofcourse you should comment out the SanitizeString for the INSERT operation after creating a user and for the SELECT statement where you check the login.

Comment: no. I get the same answer... '1' for the pass.. see the update above

Comment: I seem to pass 1 as a password each time..hmm..why 1

Comment: what is your question anyway?

Comment: lol..I solved the answer. I got 1 because when I passed the name and pass variable to that function ValidateLogin($_POST['name'],$_POST['pass']) , I did this instead ValidateLogin($_POST['name'],isset($_POST['pass'])).. my mistake..Thanks it helped. sorry for driving you nuts. Just post an answer commenting on how I can improve my hash algorithm/security and I will accept your answer

Comment: Your santizie string is crap.  xss and sqli can still make it though.  Also why would you merge these two?  They could not be more different.

Answer (score 0):

answering to your question in the comments:
You can't improve your site security with hash algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your hash/salt usage by creating a different salt for each user, instead of using the same salt for all users.